# What is the smallest length valid query string?

Tags: url, gwt, uri, query-string

What is the smallest length valid query string a URL can have?

[RFC3986#section-3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

```
The query component is indicated by the first question
mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
or by the end of the URI.
...
query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
```

So, is it length three: `pchar/?`

Or is it two: `/?`

To give some code and context, I'm inspecting this in GWT:

```
if(Location.getQueryString().isEmpty() || Location.getQueryString().length() < 1) { //or whatever valid min length for query strings is
```

My concern is basically ensuring that the query string that we're working with is valid.  So to validate that, I'm checking if it is empty.  What else should I be checking to ensure this, when working with `Location.getQueryString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window.Location.getQueryString()` is the GWT version of the JS [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.search). That means it's empty (or null? haven't checked) when the URL doesn't contain a query string at all, and starts with the `?` otherwise (meaning that it equals `?` if the query string is present but "empty", e.g. the URL ends with `?` or the `?` is directly followed by a `#`).

---

Re. the beginning of your question, `*( pchar / "/" / "?" )` means "any number of the characters either matching the *pchar* production, or `/` or `?`, `pchar` defining a set of valid characters, or %-encoded ones). So the length is determined by the `*` part of the production, which means [*0 or more*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234#section-3.6). But that defines the "content" of the query-string, without the `?` delimiter; whereas `window.location.search` will include the `?` if there's a query string in the URL.

Comment: So, if the length is 1, then it's just the `?` char (non-null) query string, which is an 'empty' query string. If it is `?#`, length 2, it is still an 'empty' query string. So, these are valid query string states, correct (since the content def is *[0 or more])? In my case, i need to check if there is a query string at all, and if so, then it must be non-empty.  In this case the length of the overall query string must be at least 2, not counting `#`, like so: `?a`.  If the length is 2, but the second char is `#`, then we still have a valid but empty query string.

Comment: Are you sure *( pchar / "/" / "?" ) is for the content that follows the first ?; would the RFC not define the query str pattern as then something like: /?*(pchar/"/"/"?"), meaning an (escaped) initial ?, following by 0 or more of pchar or `/` or `?`?

Comment: Oh, and like the example of empty query string `?#`, are `??` and `?/` also valid but empty states?

Comment: From https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3, the `query` production doesn't contain the initial `?`. Re your other question: if the URL contains `?#` then the `#` starts the `fragment` part and will be in `window.location.hash`, not `window.location.search`. If `getQueryString()` is the empty string (or `null`?), then it means the URL didn't have a query string at all; if it is equal to `?` (or length 1) then it means there is a query string but it is empty; any other value would mean that there is a non-empty query string.